# Browian motion: $P(B_1<4 | B_2 =1)$

Tags: brownian-motion

I want to calculate $P(B_1<4 | B_2 =1)$ for the B.M.

What I tried:
$P(B_1<4 | B_2 =1)=P(B_1 - B_2 < 3- B_2 | B_2 =1)$

but I cant  use any independence to calculate further.

Comment: Isn't this the same as $P(B_2<4|B_1=1)$? .  Think of running paths backwards through the known point.

Comment: @dm63 How is it the same?

Comment: Actually, I think I'm wrong if it is assumed that $B_0=0$.

Comment: Using Cholesky decomposition, you can express $B_1$ as a linear combination of $B_2$ and another normal random variable that is independent of $B_2$.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the multivariate normally distributed vector $(B_1,B_2)$, in particular
$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    B_1  \\
    B_2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$
~$N
$$\left(\begin{pmatrix}
    0  \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix},
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1  \\
    1 & 2 \\
    \end{pmatrix} 
\right)
$.

Then it holds that $B_1 |B_2=1$ ~$ N(1,1/2) $ ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions)).

Comment: Isn't it N(½,½) ?

Answer (score 4):

This is related to the concept of the [Brownian Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge).

If $B_t$ is Brownian motion then $W_t$ defined as
$$
W_t = (B_t|B_T = 0)
$$
is the Brownian bridge with end point $0$. There is version with $a$ and $b$ too.

You know where it starts and where it ends (that's why is the bridge) and there is uncertainty inbetween.
One could read-up on the topic. If I just quote wikipedia then
for $B_(t_1) = a$ and $B_(t_2) = b$ the Brownian bridge is normal with mean
$$
a + \frac{t-t_1}{t_2-t_1}(b-a)
$$
and covariance between $W(s)$ and $W(t)$
$$
\frac{(t_2-t)(s-t_1)}{t_2 - t_1}.
$$

Thus in your case we tie the Brownian bridge at $B_0 = 0$ then $t_1 = 0$ and $a=0$, $t_2 = 2$ and $b = 1$ and you have to find the probability that the Brownian bridge at time $1$ is less than $4$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I found:

$P(B_1<4 |B_2 =1) =P(2B_1 -B_2 < 7 |B_2 =1) =P(2B_1 -B_2<7 )= P(\sqrt{2} Z<7 ) = N(7/ \sqrt{2})$
where $Z$ is the standard normal r.v..
I have used the fact $2B_1 -B_2 $ is indep of $B_2$ since they are multivariate normal and their covariance is 0.